# Service reference generates soap proxy incompatible with the web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Per the WSDL that I used to get the reference, the operation I'm trying to use is defined as follows.

For reasons of security, I've replaced the service's name with "MyService" in all references.

```
<message name="MyService_fetchOperation">
    <part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="passwd" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="package" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="txType" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="swref" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="force" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

I'm building a request in C#:

```
using (var client = new MyService.MyServiceGatewayClient())
{
    response = await client.fetchOperationAsync(USER, PASS, PACKAGE, "509", "", "0");
}
```

What this request does or what its for doesn't matter in the context of this question.

The request (from Fiddler) looks like this:

```
POST https://myservice.gateway.thing HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: myservice.gateway.thing
Content-Length: 816
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="04a608d9-fbfd-4a4d-b26b-e57098352dff" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">
80000162-0005-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb</ActivityId>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo6GoRTTueVZOiE2QS303TwoAAAAA6GBrNOg50ESdf6d7KUk2nMLdj/sn/wxCqk4Df+zV1yQACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <fetchOperation xmlns="http://myservice.gateway.thing/v1">
            <user>TEST9876</user>
            <passwd>test4139</passwd><!-- plain text password ftw! -->
            <package>SWITCHON</package>
            <txType>509</txType>
            <swref/>
            <force>0</force>
        </fetchOperation>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This request returns an error on the service that it couldn't find the child element 'user'.

I've queried this with the service admin and he says I need to redefine the namespace in the `fetchOperation` tag and gave the following example:

```
<v1:fetchOperation xmlns:v1="http://myservice.gateway.thing/v1">
    ...
</v1:fetchOperation>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why would such a change be necessary? How would this fix the problem of the service not seeing the "missing" element in the request?
2. Why, if this change is needed, does the addition of the service reference in VS not generate a SOAP proxy that actually works? Is it an inconsistency on the part of the service developers or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I hit the same kind of problems using the generated code. Namespaces were one of the problems. I have made many clients and only found problems when the service is developed in other language that .net.

Comment: I already have the same issue, I resolved generating the proxy classes with `svcutil.exe` command line tool, like this: `svcutil http://url/servicesvc /Language=c#`

Comment: @RicardoPontual could you add an answer that covers the steps you used to do this? Oh is this on Windows 10 with the Windows SDK? I'm sadly stuck with Windows 8 right now. Still, it might help others if you could give more info

Comment: You didn't show us any WSDL, and that snippet of xml suggest message oriented (Java) rather than RPC (.NET) style. Pay very good attention to the options (VS wizard or cmd line) you have. SvcUtil can insert some comments worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to generate a proxy client for a service is using **svutil.exe**, a command line tool to generate service model code from metadata, web or wsdl file.

[Microsoft Docs svcutil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe)

It's included with **Visual Studio** instalation, you can open the **Developer Command Prompt** and execute it like this:

```
svcutil http://url/service.svc /Language=c#
```

You can also install `svcutil` with *Microsoft Windows SDK*: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

For a real example I've used this service: http://www.chemspider.com/MassSpecAPI.asmx

```
svcutil http://www.chemspider.com/MassSpecAPI.asmx /Language=c#
```

It was generated the `MassSpecAPI.cs` file, below part of the  generated proxy classes:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
/ ....
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://www.chemspider.com/", ClrNamespace="www.chemspider.com")]

namespace www.chemspider.com
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name="ArrayOfString", Namespace="http://www.chemspider.com/", ItemName="string")]
    public class ArrayOfString : System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
    {
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ECompression", Namespace="http://www.chemspider.com/")]
    public enum ECompression : int
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        eGzip = 0,
    }
```

Comment: But this is basically what VS Add-Reference does, you will have to play with the command line options.

Comment: Yes @HenkHolterman you are pretty right, but I had problems with some services which VS did not generate the proxy classes correctly, no matter how I tried, and svcutil resolved the issue.

Comment: Done, thanks. Now how do I implement this? I assume its not just a matter of copypasta into my project?

Comment: Yes, just copy and add to your project. The generated file contains all you need to consume the service.

Comment: That file looks pretty much identical to what ASP.NET put in the project. Still, I'll chuck it into a new project and try to use it.